# SVN options not visible in Project Explorer

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, eclipse-kepler

I am not able to view any other options apart from 'Apply patch' and 'Share project' when I right click a project and select 'Team'. I am using eclipse Kepler and Subclipse 1.10.4.

But I will be able to see the all the options if I import a project from SVN directly through eclipse workspace. I mean, right click --> Import --> SVN --> Checkout from SVN.

But the issue is, I am not sure why the options are not showing when I checkout a project in my local drive and then create a project in eclipse workspace referring to this path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to tell Eclipse to associate the project with SVN by clicking the share project button and following the wizard.

When you import an SVN project it already knows about the SVN repository so you get to skip this step.

Comment: So sharing the project means I am linking the project to already existing SVN path right? I thought that option is to create a new SVN path for a particular project. I will try the same.

Comment: If I try that option, I am getting the below error when clicking 'Share Project' ,

Comment: org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: The working copy needs to be upgraded
svn: The working copy at 'C:\Robin\projects\geCommons'
is too old (format 10) to work with client version '1.8.8 (r1568071)' (expects format 31). You need to upgrade the working copy first.


org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: The working copy needs to be upgraded
svn: The working copy at 'C:\Robin\projects\geCommons'
is too old (format 10) to work with client version '1.8.8 (r1568071)' (expects format 31). You need to upgrade the working copy first.

Comment: Yes your first comment is correct. That error means your svn client outside of eclipse is an older version than the Eclipse Plugin is using. You need to match up the versions if you want to chop and change between the two

Comment: Cool. Upgrading worked. The server version and plugin version mismatch made the problem. Thanks Cowls..!